# Parallel pg_restore unsupported

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I've used many times this technique for transferring databases between servers:

```
pg_dump --no-owner -Fd mydb -j 4 -f tmp/mydb
scp -r tmp/mydb otherserver:tmp/
```

then in the other server:

```
dropdb --if-exists mydb && 
createdb -T template0 mydb && 
pg_restore -j 4 -d mydb tmp/mydb && 
rm -rf tmp/mydb
```

It has worked flawlessly.
Using Postgres 9.3.16 and CentOS 7.

But now, in a new server, pg_restore complains:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] parallel restore is not supported with this archive file format
```

I could remove the `-j 4` parameter, but theorically it should be valid.
According to the [pg_restore doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgrestore.html):

> -j number-of-jobs
>   --jobs=number-of-jobs
>
> Run the most time-consuming parts of pg_restore — those which load
>   data, create indexes, or create constraints — using multiple
>   concurrent jobs. This option can dramatically reduce the time to
>   restore a large database to a server running on a multiprocessor
>   machine.
>
> Each job is one process or one thread, depending on the operating
>   system, and uses a separate connection to the server.
>
> The optimal value for this option depends on the hardware setup of the
>   server, of the client, and of the network. Factors include the number
>   of CPU cores and the disk setup. A good place to start is the number
>   of CPU cores on the server, but values larger than that can also lead
>   to faster restore times in many cases. Of course, values that are too
>   high will lead to decreased performance because of thrashing.
>
> Only the custom and directory archive formats are supported with this
>   option. The input must be a regular file or directory (not, for
>   example, a pipe). This option is ignored when emitting a script rather
>   than connecting directly to a database server. Also, multiple jobs
>   cannot be used together with the option --single-transaction.

I'm using the directory format in `pg_dump`: `-Fd` !
Why does it complain?

Comment: Maybe you could check the postgreSQL version on the new server ?

Comment: Maybe you could add the -fd option in pg_restore... Documentation says it's not necessary but maybe it could help...

Comment: Thanks @Arkhena, Version 9.3.16.  Adding the `-Fd` option doesn't help.  :-(

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why, but I have as server Postgres 9.3 and `psql`, `pg_restore` and `pg_dump` belong to version 9.2.

/usr/bin/pg_restore is version 9.2, but /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dump is version 9.3.

This is the cause of the problem.

```
postgresql.x86_64                                     9.2.18-1.el7                                  @base      
postgresql-devel.x86_64                               9.2.18-1.el7                                  @base      
postgresql-libs.x86_64                                9.2.18-1.el7                                  @base      
postgresql-odbc.x86_64                                09.03.0100-2.el7                              @base      
postgresql93.x86_64                                   9.3.17-1PGDG.rhel7                            @pgdg93    
postgresql93-contrib.x86_64                           9.3.17-1PGDG.rhel7                            @pgdg93    
postgresql93-libs.x86_64                              9.3.17-1PGDG.rhel7                            @pgdg93    
postgresql93-server.x86_64                            9.3.17-1PGDG.rhel7                            @pgdg93
```

The solution is simply:

```
yum remove postgresql
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with restoring a database dump but on Digital Ocean.

The issue is the `-jobs 4` flag. Which in your case i suspect to be `-j 4`. Remove this so that it does this in a single thread. According to the [link](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/import-databases/)

```
The --jobs flag to specify the number of concurrent threads to run the import. 
A higher number accelerates the process, but requires more CPUs.
```